# VB.Net how to find if one number is more than three times in array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, duplicates

I'm using Visual Basic,
I have a problem with my good, I have an array with 9 numbers, so I want array to not have same number more than 3 times..

```
Dim PArray= New Integer() {30, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000}
Dim T1(8) As Integer
Dim a As Integer = r.Next(0, 8)
T1(i) = PArray(a)
```

As you see T1 array is filled from PArray, everything I want is to not be filled with 3 same numbers like :
ex.
T1 = {30,50,30,500,30,50,2000,100,2000} ' 30 is three times  X don't want this
So if this happens 30 to be replaced with some other number from PArray, but to be sure the other number too to not bee three times in array...

Comment: What's the problem exactly? how to find if one number is more than three times in array or how to create such random array or something else?

Comment: how to find if one number is more than two times,,,,,Two times allowed, Three times no..

Comment: The best answer here depends on what you want to happen when you find "bad" numbers. It's "too broad" as is until you clarify.

Comment: To replace with new one from Parray... So I have totally 8 numbers, and array will be filled with them, but I don't want to get three same numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the collection has 3, if not add next number.

```
Static rnd As New Random
Dim PArray = {30, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000}
Dim T1 As New List(Of Integer)
Do Until T1.Count = 8
   Dim rndValue = PArray(rnd.Next(0, PArray.Count))
   Dim cnt = N1.Where(Function(i) i = rndValue).Count
   If Not cnt = 3 Then
     T1.Add(rndValue)
   End If
Loop
```

Comment: I got exception: {"Public member 'Count' on type 'Integer()' not found."} ... And if I have to tell you I declare Parray and T1 outside of my Sub.. coz I need to call them on other Subs...

Comment: Works great I just declared PArray twice outside and inside Sub.. You're King